# PHP Copy File Intermittently Fails (Debian Squeeze, PHP 5.4, NGINX 1.2.6)

Tags: php, nginx, debian, installation, file-copying

I have some code that copies a file to a temporary location where it is later included in a zip file.

I already have the source files stored in a local cache directory, and have also stored the SHA1 hash of the original files.  The files in question are .png images, ranging from a few kb to around 500kb.

My problem is that at high server loads, the copy intermittently fails.  Upon examining my logs, I see that even though a healthy file exists in the source location, the destination contains a file with zero bytes.

So, to try and figure out what was going on and to increase reliability, I implemented a SHA1 check of the destination file, so that if it fails, I can retry the copy using the shell.

99.9% of the time, the files copy with no issue.  Occasionally, the first copy fails but then the second attempt succeeds. In a few number of cases (around 1 in 2,500; and always at high server load), both copies will fail.  In nearly all these cases SHA1 of the destination file is `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` which is consistent with an empty file.

In all occasions, the script continues, and the created zip includes an empty image file.  There is nothing in the Nginx, PHP or PHP-FPM error logs that indicates any problem.  The script will copy the same file successfully when retried.

My stack is Debian Squeeze with the .deb PHP 5.4/PHP 5.4 FPM packages and Nginx 1.2.6 on an Amazon EBS backed AMI. The file system is XFS and I am not using APC or other caching.  The problem is consistent and replicable at server loads >500 hits per second.

I cannot find any documentation of known issues that would explain this behaviour.  Can anyone provide any insight into what may be causing this issue, or provide suggestions on how I can more reliably copy an image file to a temporary location for zipping?

For reference, here is an extract of the code used to copy / recopy the files.

```
$copy = copy ($cacheFile, $outputFile);

if ($copy && file_exists($outputFile) && sha1_file($outputFile) !== $storedHash) {

    // Custom function to log debug messages
    dbug(array($cacheFile, sha1_file($cacheFile), 
                   $storedHash, $outputFile, 
                   file_exists($outputFile), filesize($outputFile)), 
                   'Corrupt Image File Copy from Cache 1 (native)');

    // Try with exec
    exec ("cp " . $cacheFile . " " . $outputFile);

    if (file_exists($outputFile) && sha1_file($outputFile) !== $storedHash)
    dbug(array($cacheFile, sha1_file($cacheFile), 
                   $storedHash, $outputFile, 
                   file_exists($outputFile), filesize($outputFile)), 
                   'Corrupt Image File Copy from Cache 2 (shell exec)');
}
```

Comment: `copy()` returns a value, you should check that out and see if copy knows that it failed.

Comment: I am doing `copy()` on the first attempt - if this fails, I am using exec as a fallback.  I have tried using `copy()` as the fallback but it also fails the same as `exec` in a few number of cases.  The choice to use `exec` as a fallback was to rule out any PHP related issues.

Comment: @Leigh - Have just added a check, will need to wait a few minutes for a failure to occur, although this still doesn't explain the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: @Leigh - `copy()` returned true, still created an empty file.

Comment: If sometimes both the `copy` and the `cp` fail, I think you can rule out PHP as the cause of the issue. I really don't have any ideas what it could be though.

Comment: You copy a `$cacheFile` to `$outputFile`, could it be that on heavy loads your source file is being edited/replaced/locked while you are trying to copy it? The `cache` part on your variable name makes me fear this source file is the part suffering on heavy loads, what is the part of the application copying files on your local cache?.

Comment: @regilero I guess that locked could be a possibility. Our traffic patter has huge spikes so perhaps another copy process could be locking the file? Our app auto scales and downloads static content from S3 to a local cache, hence the name of the variable, otherwise, the file is never changes.

Comment: try increasing the number of maximum open files (ulimit) at the os level. if it is a file locking problem, create a lock file and if the file is locked try a little later